# How do I register my college in the Mozilla Campus club?

Tags: mozilla

I have completed all the required training but still not getting where I can Register my club from college

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mozilla Campus Clubs program is not an active program any more with this structure.

However, you can register your existing University Club with Mozilla, [on the new Community Portal.](https://community.mozilla.org/)

Comment: I think It will start probably in September or October...

Answer (score 2):

The program was closed a while ago, the best place is discourse and not stackoverflow to reach also the rest of the community https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/frequently-asked-questions-faq/10691

Comment: Is it close forever?

Comment: Well when Mozilla close something, is closed maybe change name and do something similar. Anyway I know that the community manager that started this project in Mozilla is following something else now but not clubs or similar.

Comment: Do they launch program probably in September or October?

Comment: No it is closed since few years, just check their socials/forum/etc

Comment: Just check the website or their social reference to get in touch, it isn't planned any launch at all